# Convert string [,] into string representation

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#

Let say I have this two-dimensional array:

```
let a = Array2D.create 2 2 "*"
```

What is an idiomatic way to turn that into the following string?

```
**\n
**\n
```

My thought would be that I need to iterate over the rows and then map `string.concat` over the items in each row. However I can't seem to figure out how to iterate just the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to iterate over the rows by hand (`Array2D` does not have any handy function for this),
but you can get a row using splicing syntax. To get the row at index `row`, you can write `array.[row, *]`:

```
let a = Array2D.create 3 2 "*"
[ for row in 0 .. a.GetLength(0)-1 ->
    String.concat "" a.[row,*] ]
|> String.concat "\n"
```

This creates a list of rows (each turned into a string using the first `String.concat`) and then concatenates the rows using the second `String.concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use `StringBuilder` and involve `Array2D.iteri` function:

```
let data' = [|[|"a"; "b"; "c"|]; [|"d"; "e"; "f"|]|]
let data = Array2D.init 2 3 (fun i j -> data'.[i].[j]) 

open System.Text
let concatenateArray2D (data:string[,]) =
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
    data
    |> Array2D.iteri (fun row col value ->
        (if col=0 && row<>0 then sb.Append "\n" else sb)
            .Append value |> ignore
        )
    sb.ToString()

data |> concatenateArray2D |> printfn "%s"
```

This prints:

```
abc
def
```